# how to method chain describe(), value_counts(), and to_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series, chaining

Here is my code

```
#import modules
import pandas as pd

#assign pd.read_csv() to infile to read in data from a datafile
infile = pd.read_csv('..\Infiles\\StarWars_Data.txt')

#get user input for selecting a Series name
Series_name = input("please enter the name of one of the series's for closer inspection")

#Select the Series
Series_Data = infile[Series_name]

#Chain the value_counts(), and describe() and to_csv() methods
Series_Data.value_counts()\
    .describe()\
    .to_csv('..\Outfiles\StarWars_Results.txt')
```

I expect it to perform `value_counts()` (returns the numbers of unique values in a series), `describe()` (gives summary statistics on a series), and `to_csv`(writes what is stored into a specified csv file).

For some reason `to_csv()` is returning `describe()` but it is not returning `value_counts()`, how do I write the data from both `value_counts()` and `describe()` to the same document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, do you want?

```
 pd.concat([df['words'].value_counts(),
            df['words'].describe()])\
   .to_csv('..\Outfiles\StarWars_Results.txt')
```

MCVE:

```
s = pd.Series([*'AABBBBCDDEEEEEEE'])

pd.concat([s.value_counts(), s.describe()]).rename_axis('key').to_csv('a.text')

!type a.txt
```

Output:

```
key,0
E,7
B,4
A,2
D,2
C,1
count,16
unique,5
top,E
freq,7
```

Comment: this is returning an error 'list object has no attribute to_csv'

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: `pd.concat` returns a dataframe not a list.  Therefore your error you have listed here doesn't make any sense to the above line of code.

Comment: I am using the most recent version 1.1.4

Comment: Yep.  Create a dummy series and test.

Comment: It worked when I hardcoded the series name instead of using a variable

Comment: I was able to softcode it, my code looks like this 
    pd.concat([infile[Series_name].value_counts(),
        infile[Series_name].describe()])\
        to_csv('..\Outfiles\StarWars_Results.txt')